# Generate images from large list of words

Tags: script, image-processing

This is a bit of an odd question, but basically I'm trying to create a set of Pictionary cards for a game. To do this, I have a list of 1500 nouns separated by newlines and I need each of them to be placed on individual PNG files of a specific resolution. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: Do you have any design software available (or preferred) such as Photoshop, Illustrator, or InDesign?

Comment: @JohnB Just paint.net, nothing that costs money

Comment: GIMP supports scripting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple task for [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/). The [caption tool](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#caption) allows for word wrapping, though if it's just nouns then that might not be a concern. An example command would look like this:

```
convert -background black -fill white -pointsize 32 \
        -size 500x300 -gravity center caption:'WORD' WORD.png
```

Here's the resulting PNG:

[image]

Then all you need is a script to input your words file and feed them in to that command. Here's [how to do it with bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10929511/1832306):

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    convert -background black -fill white -pointsize 32 \
            -size 500x300 -gravity center caption:$line $line.png
done < "$1"
```

Usage would be `./scriptname words-file.txt`

Comment: +1 WORST CASE, without bash, the OP can find and replace on newline using notepad++ to emit a 1500 line bat file (not recommended)

Comment: This works. FYI, for future readers, this can be done in widows like this: FOR /F %%i IN (words.txt) DO convert -background white -fill black -pointsize 60 -size 582x408 -gravity center caption:%%i %%i.png